# Can I sense.set_pixels every second without using sleep?

Tags: python, time, raspberry-pi

I'm currently working on a project in Java with a Raspberry Pi - I've only been coding for a few months and I am still learning.

I'm making an animation that will run for nine seconds. I have nine frames and I would like each frame to show for one second. Initially, I used the sleep function, but eventually I need to add this code to a larger project and cannot use sleep.

```
  from sense_hat import SenseHat
  from time import sleep

  sense = SenseHat()

  #colours

  r = (255, 0, 0)
  o = (255,165,0)
  y = (255, 216, 1)
  g = (21, 119, 40)
  b = (0, 70, 255)
  p = (100, 50, 200)
  e = (0, 0, 0,)
  w = (255, 255, 255)
  u = (101, 67, 33) #brown

  #frames for animations

  egg1 = [
  g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,
  e,e,e,e,p,p,e,e,
  e,e,e,p,y,w,p,e,
  e,e,p,y,w,w,y,p,
  e,e,p,y,w,y,w,p,
  e,e,e,p,w,y,p,e,
  e,e,p,e,p,p,e,e,
  e,p,e,e,e,e,e,e,
  ]

 egg2 = [
 r,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,
 e,e,e,e,p,p,e,e,
 e,e,e,p,y,w,p,e,
 e,e,p,y,w,w,y,p,
 e,e,p,y,w,y,w,p,
 e,e,e,p,w,y,p,e,
 e,e,p,e,p,p,e,e,
 e,p,e,e,e,e,e,e,
 ]

 egg3 = [
 r,r,g,g,g,g,g,g,
 e,e,e,e,p,p,e,e,
 e,e,e,p,y,w,p,e,
 e,e,p,y,w,w,y,p,
 e,e,p,y,w,y,w,p,
 e,e,e,p,w,y,p,e,
 e,e,p,e,p,p,e,e,
 e,p,e,e,e,e,e,e,
 ]

 egg4 = [
 r,r,r,g,g,g,g,g,
 e,e,e,e,p,p,e,e,
 e,e,e,p,o,y,p,e,
 e,e,p,o,y,y,o,p,
 e,e,p,o,y,o,o,p,
 e,e,e,p,y,o,p,e,
 e,e,p,e,p,p,e,e,
 e,p,e,e,e,e,e,e,
 ]

 egg5 = [
 r,r,r,r,g,g,g,g,
 e,e,e,e,p,p,e,e,
 e,e,e,p,o,y,p,e,
 e,e,p,o,y,y,o,p,
 e,e,p,o,y,o,o,p,
 e,e,e,p,y,o,p,e,
 e,e,p,e,p,p,e,e,
 e,p,e,e,e,e,e,e,
 ]

 egg6 = [
 r,r,r,r,r,g,g,g,
 e,e,e,e,p,p,e,e,
 e,e,e,p,o,y,p,e,
 e,e,p,o,y,y,o,p,
 e,e,p,o,y,o,o,p,
 e,e,e,p,y,o,p,e,
 e,e,p,e,p,p,e,e,
 e,p,e,e,e,e,e,e,
 ]

 egg7 = [
 r,r,r,r,r,r,g,g,
 e,e,e,e,p,p,e,e,
 e,e,e,p,u,o,p,e,
 e,e,p,u,o,o,u,p,
 e,e,p,u,o,u,o,p,
 e,e,e,p,o,u,p,e,
 e,e,p,e,p,p,e,e,
 e,p,e,e,e,e,e,e,
 ]


 egg8 = [
 r,r,r,r,r,r,r,g,
 e,e,e,e,p,p,e,e,
 e,e,e,p,u,o,p,e,
 e,e,p,u,o,o,u,p,
 e,e,p,u,o,u,o,p,
 e,e,e,p,o,u,p,e,
 e,e,p,e,p,p,e,e,
 e,p,e,e,e,e,e,e,
 ]

 egg9 = [
 r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,
 e,e,e,e,p,p,e,e,
 e,e,e,p,u,o,p,e,
 e,e,p,u,o,o,u,p,
 e,e,p,u,o,u,o,p,
 e,e,e,p,o,u,p,e,
 e,e,p,e,p,p,e,e,
 e,p,e,e,e,e,e,e,
 ]

 while True:
      for event in sense.stick.get_events():
       #check if pressed
          if event.action == "pressed":
        
             #check direction
             if event.direction == "up":
             sense.set_pixels(egg1)
             sleep(1)
             sense.set_pixels(egg2)
             sleep(1)
             sense.set_pixels(egg3)
             sleep(1)
             sense.set_pixels(egg4)
             sleep(1)
             sense.set_pixels(egg5)
             sleep(1)
             sense.set_pixels(egg6)
             sleep(1)
             sense.set_pixels(egg7)
             sleep(1)
             sense.set_pixels(egg8)
             sleep(1)
             sense.set_pixels(egg9)
             sleep(1)
```

I tried using time, but for some reason it will print both of the test messages at the same time instead of waiting one second between each.

```
import time

t0 = time.time()

print("test")

if t0 > 1:
     print ("test1")
```

I also tried this:

```
 import time

 oldtime = import sleep

 while True:

 if time.time() - oldtime > 1:
      print("1")

 if time.time() - oldtime > 2:
      print("2")

 if time.time() - oldtime > 3:
      print("3")
```

What is the simplest way to sense.set_pixels to something different every second without using the sleep function?

Comment: Put them all in a list.  `eggs = [egg1,egg2,egg3,egg4...egg9]`.  Now you can just do: `for i in range(9):` / `sense.set_pixel(eggs[i])` / `sleep(1)`

Comment: Your second example doesn't do any waiting.  `time.time()` simply returns the number of seconds since January 1, 1970.  It will always be > 1.

Comment: The only way to skip `sleep` is if you have an event system with a timer that can call you back periodically.  All of the GUI libraries have that.